# configure pip to get missing package from pypi.python.org

Tags: python, pip, config, pypi

I have local `pypi` server.

and I set it configuration in

```
root@localhost$ cat .pip/pip.conf
[global]
index-url = http://localhost/simple
trusted-host=localhost
```

My `pypi` server has `paste=2.0.2` but one of the app need `paste=2.0.3`. when I check in `https://pypi.python.org/simple/paste/` it has this version.

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` it gives below error.

```
Collecting paste==2.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  1 location(s) to search for versions of paste:
  * http://localhost/simple/paste/
  Getting page http://localhost/simple/paste/
  Resetting dropped connection: localhost
  "GET /simple/paste/ HTTP/1.1" 200 309
  Analyzing links from page http://localhost/simple/paste/
    Found link http://localhost/packages/Paste-2.0.2-py2-none-any.whl#md5=42d3df8ad533457607903a0ca0922825 (from http://localhost/simple/paste/), version: 2.0.2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paste==2.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22)) (from versions: 2.0.2)
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for paste==2.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 276, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for paste==2.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
You are using pip version 9.0.0, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How can I configure `pip.conf`, so when specific package with number is not available on `local` pypi, it will search for `pypi.python.org`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set

```
[global]
extra-index-url =  https://pypi.python.org
```

in your ~/.pip/pip.conf file per the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#client-side-configurations)

Furthermore, you can start you pypi server with the following argument

```
  --fallback-url FALLBACK_URL
    for packages not found in the local index, this URL will be used to
    redirect to (default: http://pypi.python.org/simple)
```

Comment: as per documents `default: http://pypi.python.org/simple` means if we not give `--fallback-url` then by default it has to redirect to `pypi.python.org`, I tired `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` by setting to default pypi server. But still it failing with same error.

Comment: Alex, for me, `package` is there `paste`, but it not exists with `proper` version.